# Unable to connect to wss [Update]

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket, wss

I'm new in java.
I want to connect to web socket like this:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class PrimeBot {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        // open websocket
        final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI("wss://example.com"));

        // add listener
        clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(new WebsocketClientEndpoint.MessageHandler() {
            public void handleMessage(String message) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        });

        // send message to websocket
        clientEndPoint.sendMessage("{''}");

        // wait 3 seconds for messages from websocket
        Thread.sleep(3000);

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println("InterruptedException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Second class

```
import java.net.URI;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

@ClientEndpoint
public class WebsocketClientEndpoint {

Session userSession = null;
private MessageHandler messageHandler;

public WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI) {
    try {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback hook for Connection open events.
 *
 * @param userSession the userSession which is opened.
 */
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
    System.out.println("opening websocket");
    this.userSession = userSession;
}

/**
 * Callback hook for Connection close events.
 *
 * @param userSession the userSession which is getting closed.
 * @param reason the reason for connection close
 */
@OnClose
public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
    System.out.println("closing websocket");
    this.userSession = null;
}

/**
 * Callback hook for Message Events. This method will be invoked when a client send a message.
 *
 * @param message The text message
 */
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message) {
    if (this.messageHandler != null) {
        this.messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
    }
}

/**
 * register message handler
 *
 * @param message
 */
public void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler) {
    this.messageHandler = msgHandler;
}

/**
 * Send a message.
 *
 * @param user
 * @param message
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
}

/**
 * Message handler.
 *
 * @author Jiji_Sasidharan
 */
public static interface MessageHandler {

    public void handleMessage(String message);
}
}
```

I included:
- gson-2.5.jar
- javax.websocket-client-api-1.1.jar
- tyrus-client-1.12.jar
- tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.12.jar

and still getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/tyrus/spi/ClientContainer
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyContainerProvider.getContainer(GrizzlyContainerProvider.java:53)
at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(ContainerProvider.java:67)
at WebsocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:24)
at PrimeBot.main(PrimeBot.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
org.glassfish.tyrus.spi.ClientContainer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
```

Comment: How have you included your client jar and how are you running this app?

Comment: This way I include jars: right click on project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add external jars -> OK

I running this app by clikcking on Run and choose  "run as Java Application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you either start using tools like maven/ivy/gradle so you could get all the dependencies or you would be dealing with individual dependancies and would face similar issues later down the line.

Inorder to solve your issue, you would need `tyrus-spi-1.12.jar` in your classpath which you could download from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/tyrus/tyrus-spi/1.12/tyrus-spi-1.12.jar)